# Swift viewcontroller firebase database observer repeat calling

Tags: firebase, swift3, uiviewcontroller, triggers, firebase-realtime-database

In my xcode project, I have 2 view controllers: A and B, they all connect to the same firebase reference nod, and listening to the same data.

My problem is, For example: if i go back and forth between these two view controllers for 7 times (or as many times as i go back and forth between that A and B view controllers) once i clicked  a button perform an action, a firebase observer is triggered, view controller A is triggered for 7 times, because I added

```
print("action is triggered")
```

in view controller A, and this line is print 7 times in the debugger. I kept trying to figure out why 7 times, where the count is saved? I tried to remove firebase observer using the documents provided from Firebase, but no luck, maybe problem is coming from shuttling back and forth between these view controllers. These view controllers never have been removed, but I never recall I need to remove a view controller! I try to find any discussion here and google it, and I had no luck.

All I try to do is detect data change inside firebase database, if something changed in database, the button function changed and perform certain different function. All works fine, until I found out this loop  problem. Has anyone else ever encountered the same problem?

Comment: You are probably setting new listners each time you show the controller. Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out to remove the repeating process i can use remove observer which provided by the firebase document, and the repeating problem is solved, your hint works great, i googled the topic hint and found answer at the stack flow. thanks